# How to see top 20 contents of an H2o frame in spark?

Tags: h2o

I have converted a dataframe to and h2oframe as follows:

```
val myH2OFrame = h2oContext.asH2OFrame(mydatframe, "myH2OFrame")
```

But I get a "cannot resolve symbol" error whenever I try to print rows using:

```
myH2OFrame.show
```

So how can I see the contents of an h2oframe?

Comment: here is the link to the docs as well: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-scala_2.11/scaladoc/index.html#water.fvec.H2OFrame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `myH2OFrame.toString(0, 20, false)` which gives you a preview

**or**

you can do `myH2OFrame.toTwoDimTable(0, 20, false)` to get first twenty rows as an object which holds actual numbers (or strings)